# Running a build process on Team Foundation Server

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've been working on getting a Team Foundation Server working for days now.

I've spent ages trying to figure out how to work in on my own computer, only to find that installing it on a fresh machine answered the basic questions of why I couldn't connect.

Now I've got a git repo connected, build processes defined, from visual studio I'm able to execute a "Queue Build" command - but the following error comes up every time (though it's taken me days to get this far)

```
 TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \MyProject: 
 Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
 Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

 Inner Exception Details:

 Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs.myserver.com. (type VssUnauthorizedException)
 Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.<DownloadFileFromTfsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

If I look to the "Inner Exception" I can indeed see that there appears to be a problem with the TFS connection

The TFS default install is sitting on a virtual directory in the path `http://tfs.myserver.com/tfs`

However, it appears that this build process trying to connect to the build machine using its own external URL while the team foundation server is configured to allow self-communication on localhost.

Does anyone have any experience with making sure that build processes are able to actually build on a Team Foundation Server?

This is TFS 2013 Express on a 2012 server.

Comment: Ummm. I have set up a Tfs server and build server on the same virtual machine. The repo is Git as well. Have you got any other websites on your local server? have you disabled loopback check if you are using a DNS other than your machine name?

Comment: Thanks Hamid, I have not yet tried disabling loopback check  I will try that.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem with my TFS 2013.

Comment: Same problem here, have you solve it?

Comment: I'm sorry - I never solved this.  I abandoned the path as "not economical" and use visualstudioonline. It's annoying that I couldn't get it to work, but at the end of the day it wasn't the "core business" I was after and instead was intended to enable the core business which was developing a site. Others on my team since switched to Jenkins and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369989/unable-to-build-with-the-new-tfvctemplate-12-xaml), and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99b9f8c3-4de5-4c0a-a5fb-63e5f5e3f901/unable-to-build-with-the-new-tfvctemplate12xaml?forum=tfsbuild#70006c20-2a63-415f-8fcf-fb294d5725fc)):

"Can you download the default TfsTemplate.12.xaml from build definition to local folder? If yes, please try the below steps:

1. Create a BuildProcessTemplates folder under your team project in Source Control Explorer, and check-in it to your team project Source Control.
2. Download the TfsTemplate.12.xaml template to local path, then add it into that BuildProcessTemplates folder in Source Control Explorer, then perform check-in.
3. In your build definition>>Process tab, click New… button to add the TfsTemplate.12.xaml from that BuildProcessTemplates folder in your team project Source Control, and save your build definition.
4. Queue your build definition and check result."