# Unable to Build with the new TfvcTemplate.12.xaml

Tags: templates, build

I tried to used the new template TfvcTemplate.12.xaml with my Builds (Vs 2013) but each time I received the following error message :

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \path\Buildname: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs.mydomain.com:8080. (type VssUnauthorizedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.<DownloadFileFromTfsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

I tried to find an answer with the error code, but nothing seems to be linking on my problem. Could you help me? :)

Thanks

Comment: Glad to see i'm not the only one. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Hi Robert. You need to download the template before you use it.
Create a BuildProcessTemplates folder under your team project in Source Control Explorer, and check-in it to your team project Source Control.
Download the TfsTemplate.12.xaml template to local path, then add it into that BuildProcessTemplates folder in Source Control Explorer, then perform check-in.
In your build definition>>Process tab, click New… button to add the TfsTemplate.12.xaml from that BuildProcessTemplates folder in your team project Source Control, and save your build definition.

Comment: Link where I was answered : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99b9f8c3-4de5-4c0a-a5fb-63e5f5e3f901/unable-to-build-with-the-new-tfvctemplate12xaml?forum=tfsbuild#70006c20-2a63-415f-8fcf-fb294d5725fc